# Как сделать множественный выбор в фильтре?

Tags: wordpress

на сайте есть фильтр, один из его пунктов это выбор микрорайона(taxonomy), сейчас это сделано в виде selecta(и фильтр работает) , но мне нужно чтобы это было в виде чекбоксов

```
<?php
    if( $terms = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'houses', 'orderby' => 'name' ) ) ) : 

        echo '<select name="categoryfilter"><option value="">Выберите микрорайон</option>';
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) :
            echo '<option value="' . $term->term_id . '">' . $term->name . '</option>';
        endforeach;
        echo '</select>';
    endif;
?>
```

functions.php

```
if( isset( $_POST['categoryfilter'] ) )
    $args['tax_query'] = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'houses',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $_POST['categoryfilter']
        )
    );
```

Пробовал так

```
<?php
    if( $terms = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'houses', 'orderby' => 'name' ) ) ) : 

        echo '<div>';
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) :
            echo '<label><input type="checkbox" name="categoryfilter" value="' . $term->term_id . '">' . $term->name . '</label>';
        endforeach;
        echo '</div>';
    endif;
?>
```

Но не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте таким образом:

```
<?php
    if( $terms = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'houses', 'orderby' => 'name' ) ) ) : 

        echo '<div>';
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) :
            echo '<label><input type="checkbox" name="categoryfilter[]" value="' . $term->term_id . '">' . $term->name . '</label>';
        endforeach;
        echo '</div>';
    endif;
?>
```

К вашему коду добавил `type="checkbox"`, а так же в `name="categoryfilter[]"` чтобы можно было передать значения вашего чекбокса в качестве массива.

Comment: спасибо, type="checkbox" я просто в вопрос не скопировал, а вот в качестве массива помогло

Answer (score 0):

нет типа у тега input

```
echo '<label><input type="checkbox" name="categoryfilter[]" value="' . $term->term_id . '">' . $term->name . '</label>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю радиокнопки, так как ваш код не готов принимать несколько выбранных значений

```
echo '<label><input type="radio" name="categoryfilter" value="' . $term->term_id . '">' . $term->name . '</label>';
```